# iOS - add two-finger gesture on scrollview with scrollViewDidZoom and touchesMoved

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm working on adding a two-finger gesture to pan on a custom 3D view that is in a `UIScrollView`. The inner workings isn't made by me and is just calculation of points and how to plot them to the 3D view. My main concern is the `scrollViewDidZoom` and `touchesMoved` functions conflicting with the approaches I've tried.

I've tried counting the `touches` of the `touchesMoved` function, but it's not very stable.

I've tried adding a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` but it conflicts with the `scrollViewDidZoom`. Also, since I'm using a custom one, the `minimumNumberOfTouches` and `maximumNumberOfTouches` property is not working as expected.

I want to know how to add a two-finger gesture that won't conflict with the existing gestures in the view.

This is written in Obj-c hence the tag, but answers in Swift are welcomed.

This is an excerpt of the code. It's not revealing much, but basically I want to have better control of the `panMode` bool.

```
- (UIView*)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView*)scrollView {
    return zoomDummyView;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView*)scrollView {

    if ([scrollView zoomScale] != 3.0f)
    {
        //do calculation on zooming
    }
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {

    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

    NSArray* array = [touches allObjects];

    //this is what I've tried so far - check count of touches and then use the bool to denote pan mode or not

    panMode = array.count > 1 ? true : false

    for ( int i = 0; i < [array count]; ++i )
    {
        //do point calculation    
    }
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {

    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];


    NSArray* array = [touches allObjects];
    for ( int i = 0; i < [array count]; ++i )
    {
        //some point calculation

    // simulation of mouse control for the 3D view, as you can see panMode is used to indicate movement between tilt and pan.

        input.isLeftButtonDown = !panMode; // for tilt mode
        input.isRightButtonDown = false;
        input.isMiddleButtonDown = panMode; // for pan mode
        input.isSideButton1Down = false;
        input.isSideButton2Down = false;

        //input simulation
    }
}
```

Comment: let's try this - https://gabrielghe.github.io/swift/2016/03/20/swipable-uitableviewcell

Comment: Sorry for the broad question. I was asking about scrollViews. This has nothing to do with UITableViewCells or swipes.